# How can I deploy the auth0 app to bluemix

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

I am using a sample project from auth0.com to customize the login page for my app and enable social media login. However I encounter some problem when I try to deploy it to bluemix.
The video tutorial I follow is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sHhNoV-sS_I&t=559s
however the sample project is a little bit different from the one in video. It required the command "npm serve" to run it. When I push my project using cf push it shows noappdecked. How can I deploy my project to bluemix?
the app.js code and html code is like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Auth0-VanillaJS</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- Auth0 lock script -->
    <script src="//cdn.auth0.com/js/lock/10.3.0/lock.min.js"></script>
    <script src="auth0-variables.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <img alt="avatar" id="avatar" style="display:none;">
    <p>Welcome <span id="nickname"></span></p>
    <button type="submit" id="btn-login">Sign In</button>
    <button type="submit" id="btn-logout" style="display:none;">Sign Out</button>
  </body>
```

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

  var lock = new Auth0Lock(AUTH0_CLIENT_ID, AUTH0_DOMAIN);

  // buttons
  var btn_login = document.getElementById('btn-login');
  var btn_logout = document.getElementById('btn-logout');

  btn_login.addEventListener('click', function() {
    lock.show();
  });

  btn_logout.addEventListener('click', function() {
    logout();
  });

  lock.on("authenticated", function(authResult) {
    lock.getProfile(authResult.idToken, function(error, profile) {
      if (error) {
        // Handle error
        return;
      }
      localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
      // Display user information
      show_profile_info(profile);
    });
  });

  //retrieve the profile:
  var retrieve_profile = function() {
    var id_token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
    if (id_token) {
      lock.getProfile(id_token, function (err, profile) {
        if (err) {
          return alert('There was an error getting the profile: ' + err.message);
        }
        // Display user information
        show_profile_info(profile);
      });
    }
  };

  var show_profile_info = function(profile) {
    var avatar = document.getElementById('avatar');
    document.getElementById('nickname').textContent = profile.nickname;
    btn_login.style.display = "none";
    avatar.src = profile.picture;
    avatar.style.display = "block";
    btn_logout.style.display = "block";
  };

  var logout = function() {
    localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
    window.location.href = "/";
  };

  retrieve_profile();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use the `package.json` method documented at https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/runtimes/nodejs/index.html#nodejs_runtime , first to declare the `serve` package as one of your dependencies, then to indicate what the `scripts.start` script should do (which is run `npm serve`). You can use `npm init` (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init) to create a starting `package.json` file if you don't already have one.

Comment: I added the package.json with   "scripts": {
    "start": "serve"
  },but it still don't work. Did I miss the part you mention by "declare dependencies"? How should I do that?

Comment: Invoke your npm installs with `--save` to add them to the list of dependencies in the `package.json` file, or look at the reference doc for how to write them yourself: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json